# Element visible before the time mentioned for wait so Will the implicit/Explicit wait still wait till the time mentioned or click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

If I have given 30sec of implicit wait for an element to click,and the script is able to find the element in 10th second itself,will it still wait or click the element?
The same situation,I want to know for explicit wait too..will it wait or click it on the 10th second itself??

Comment: The value you provide is the maximum time webdriver will wait. If it crosses that it will throw the Element Not Found Exception. If it finds the element before the timeout it will go ahead with the program. Note of caution, if you mix implicit and explicit waits you are going to be in a world of pain with long wait times.

Comment: @Grasshopper: 
Yeah..I got it.. :)I am using both in different situations..So mostly we use explicit right? Like in case of button click..page load..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Implicit wait` means `findElement()` and `findElements()` methods will try to locate the element(s) up to specified amount of time. The only condition is that the element(s) exists in the DOM.

`Explicit wait` means the driver will try to locate the element and then check if the located element is in the expected state (visible, enabled, stale etc).

Both waits samples the DOM every 500 ms (default) until the condition is met **or** the specified time ends, the earlier one (unlike `Thread.sleep(30000)` that will hold the program for 30 seconds no meter what).